# Can't install cvxopt on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I tried installing cvxopt using Terminal but I keep getting the following message :

> lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:
>   /var/folders/p2/_njkvzqj50zg3_568vpqc68r0000gn/T//ccRX9bFW.out error:
>   command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

What is causing this problem ?

Comment: Which version of osx are you using? Could it be the same type of problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839795/cant-figure-out-the-architecture-type-of-problem-when-compiling-python)?

Comment: Mountaion OSX 10.8 -- Im not sure what version of python im using (32bit or 64bit)

Comment: Correction, im using the 64bit version

Answer (score 2):

I don't think cvxopt supports OSX 10.8 yet. (you may ask on their [googlegroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cvxopt) )
I know, however, that in principle it is possible to build cvxopt on OSX 10.8, via Sage (www dot sagemath dot org - argh, I can only have 2 hyperlinks in the post :)). This is highly [experimental](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sage-devel/dq0GiKFJ9Zc/eiXVS9X104UJ) at present, as Sage does not officially support OSX 10.8 yet.